# How would you go about getting the small signal transfer function for this inverting circuit?

Tags: transfer-function

I am trying to get the small signal transfer function for a circuit that looks like this:
[image: It is an inverting amplifier connected to an output and a capacitor in series with an inductor]

It is an inverting amplifier connected to an output branch and a branch with a capacitor in series with an inductor. I have not been able to figure out how the small signal transfer function would look for something like this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the TF of the inverting amplifier?

Comment: There was no TF given

Comment: If it's an ideal amplifier, then the load on the output is immaterial.  If you're seeing this on a homework problem you need to know the transfer function and output impedance of the amplifier.  If you're seeing it on a schematic you need the part number, and then you'll need to figure out the TF and output impedance.

Comment: I see what you are getting at. This was given to me by my professor as a bonus question on our last lab and I was never able to answer it so I was curious about it. This was the only diagram he gave with just the instruction of finding the small signal transfer function.

Comment: He also asked how the circuit would change if Tr << Tres, Tr = Tres, and Tr >> Tres but I did not understand that at all so I figured I would try and figure out the transfer function first. Tr being rise time and Tres being associated with the resonance frequency of the LC network.

Comment: What's "Tr" and "Tres"?

Comment: Tau_r and Tau_r which I tried to explain in the comment above

Comment: Tau_r and Tau_res*

Comment: Draw the real circuit, a TF for this diagram doesn't make sense. There is no gain on the amp and there is no source impedance for the amp. So one can only assume that it is an ideal amp, and if it is ideal the load doesn't matter, because an ideal amp can expend infinite energy to drive the load to the value it needs to be.

Comment: ..."He also asked how the circuit would change".....The circuit?? I do not expect any circuit modifications by changing some values....A rather "sloopy" wording...like the whole task.

Comment: There's obviously a whole world of silently implied background which is both so obvious to you and your professor and totally unknown to us.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get a reasonably interesting, but not impossible to calculate, answer is to assume the amplifier has a one-pole frequency response, and an arbitrary real output impedance.

Keeping the output impedance \$R_A\$ as a free parameter, you should be able to qualitatively predict the overall behavior with the given load, and also say something about how the step response would depend on the amplifier's output rise-time and the resonant frequency of the LC load.